# Macports sudo expands ~ to /var/root in python

Tags: python, macos, bash, macports, sudo

I installed the macports version of `sudo`.  All is well, except for one thing.  Using python 2.6 to expand `~` to the user's home directory results in a different output than the version of `sudo` that comes with Snow Leopard.

For example consider the following python code:

```
#expand_home_dir.py
import os

os.path.expanduser('~')
```

Below are 3 different calls of the code listed above.  The first call using sudo is using the Macports version because my `$PATH` begins with `/opt/local/bin`:

```
robert$ python2.6 expand_home_dir.py 
/Users/robert
robert$ sudo python2.6 expand_home_dir.py 
/var/root
robert$ /usr/bin/sudo python2.6 expand_home_dir.py
/Users/robert
```

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: I don't think this is due to the MacPorts version of sudo. I have *not* messed with sudo, and if I do `sudo -i`, `cd ~`, `pwd` I also receive the output `/var/root`. Perhaps you should ask if `os.path.expanduser` is the proper thing to use for Python to get the current user's path regardless of privilege escalation? (on stackoverflow)

Comment: @Ricket: using sudo -i, you're actually directly specifying that you want to change to the new user's home directory and open a new shell.  However just using sudo without the -i is where the weird behavior shows up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The HOME environment variable controls what ~ expands to. It sounds like your MacPorts-installed version of sudo is resetting HOME to the root user's home directory, while the system-installed version doesn't. What happens if you type `sudo sh -c 'echo $HOME'`?

Comment: Kevin's answer is correct.  Note that he asked you to use `'echo $HOME'`, not `"echo $HOME"`.  That makes a difference.  In the latter case, $HOME is being substituted in the original shell, not the sudo-ed one.  Read the NEWS file for sudo 1.7.4, the current MacPorts version: `/opt/local/share/doc/sudo/NEWS`.  There is a change vs the Apple 1.7.0 version: "The HOME and MAIL environment variables are now reset ...".

Comment: fyi, based on this i solved it by doing `sudo /opt/local/sbin/visudo`  and adding (or uncommenting, can't remember) `Defaults env_keep += HOME`